# Build SQLite3 database from cmake

Tags: sqlite, cmake, makefile

I have a project where I have SQL files, and I want cmake/make to generate a sqlite database for me.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

project( home_manager_sqlite )

message("Prefix is: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

#find sqlite3
find_path(SQLITE3_EXECUTABLE sqlite3)

add_custom_target(main_sqlite ALL DEPENDS ${MAIN_DB_FN} SOURCES lbus.sql)
add_custom_target(log_sqlite ALL DEPENDS ${LOG_DB_FN} SOURCES lbus_log.sql)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${MAIN_DB_FN}
                        MAIN_DEPENDENCY lbus.sql
                        COMMAND cat lbus.sql | sqlite3 -batch ${MAIN_DB_FN})

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${LOG_DB_FN}
                        MAIN_DEPENDENCY lbus_log.sql
                        COMMAND cat lbus_log.sql | sqlite3 -batch ${LOG_DB_FN})

install (FILES ${MAIN_DB_FN}
            DESTINATION ${DB_INSTALL_DIR}
            RENAME ${MAIN_DB_FN}.sample
            PERMISSIONS OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
                GROUP_READ GROUP_WRITE
                WORLD_READ)

install (FILES ${LOG_DB_FN}
            DESTINATION ${DB_INSTALL_DIR}
            RENAME ${LOG_DB_FN}.sample
            PERMISSIONS OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
                GROUP_READ GROUP_WRITE
                WORLD_READ)

install (CODE "execute_process(COMMAND chown -R ${WWW_OWNER} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${DB_INSTALL_DIR})")
```

This somehow works, but when I do out of source build, the sql files are not found.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "out of source build"? If you want to run cmake from, say, `build` directory (which is usually done not to pollute source tree with temporary files), you should prefer absolute paths for files, like

```
set(MAIN_DB_FN ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x.db)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${MAIN_DB_FN}
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY lbus.sql
  COMMAND sqlite3 ${MAIN_DB_FN} < lbus.sql
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Then if you create a `build` in your source repository root directory and run `cmake ..` there, you will get build/x.db created.